# GAE BigQuery works on dev server, but HTTP 400 error when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Made a GAE Standard app that saves .JSON to Google Cloud Storage and then loads the .JSON into BigQuery with schema. Writing and running this via Google Cloud Shell.

The script works when launched on dev server (saved .JSON, loads BQ table). The script errors when deployed and hitting the appspot URL. The error is talking about the schema...but it works just fine on dev.

Error when deployed and hitting appspot URL:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/api-gcs/jobs?alt=json returned "Required parameter: [resource.configuration.load.schema.field[0].name]">

Code:

```
import cloudstorage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import json
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os
import webapp2

# This handler creates a file in Cloud Storage using the cloudstorage
# client library and then reads the data back using the Blobstore API.
class CreateAndReadFileHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        dict_test = {'date': '2018-01-02', 'username': 'pasta456', 'age': 43, 'favorite_number': 1.22}

        bucket = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()

        filename = '/{}/json_example.json'.format(bucket)

        with cloudstorage.open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
            filehandle.write(json.dumps(dict_test))

        blobstore_filename = '/gs{}'.format(filename)
        blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

        data = blobstore.fetch_data(blob_key, 0, 6)

        PROJECT = os.environ['PROJECT']
        BUCKET = os.environ['BUCKET']
        DATASET = os.environ['DATASET']

        service = build("bigquery", "v2", credentials = credentials)

        job = {
            "configuration": {
              "load": {
                "sourceUris": ["gs://XXX.appspot.com/json_example.json"],
                "schema": {
                    "fields" : [
                      {"name": "date",
                       "type": "DATE"},
                      {"name": "username",
                       "type": "STRING"},
                      {"name": "age",
                        "type": "INTEGER"},
                      {"name": "favorite_number",
                       "type": "FLOAT"}
                      ]
                },
                "destinationTable": {
                  "projectId": PROJECT,
                  "datasetId": DATASET,
                  "tableId": "json_test2"
                },
                "sourceFormat" : "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
                "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
              }   
            }
          }


        response = service.jobs().insert(
                projectId = PROJECT,
                body = job
                ).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: The fix was the JSON formatting for the schema. I still have no idea why the schema format in question would work on dev but not when deployed. Below is the schema formatting that worked on deploy.

```
            "schema": {
                "fields" : [
                  {"name": "date2", "type": "DATE"},
                  {"name": "username", "type": "STRING"},
                  {"name": "age", "type": "INTEGER"},
                  {"name": "favorite_number", "type": "FLOAT"}
                  ]
            }
```

Comment: I don't think that the fix was formatting the schema, as it's essentially exactly the same as the original schema that was posted. The error ("Required parameter: [resource.configuration.load.schema.field[0].name]">), relates to this part of the code: {"name": "date", "type": "DATE"}, and it make senses that this didn't work as 'date' is a reserved SQL word (I understand it worked in dev, but this is only a simulated environment). It therefore makes sense that changing 'date' to 'date2' in the schema then worked after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer (it is easier to add an screenshot here).

I just wanted to say that it doesn't seem to be a BigQuery issue. Using API explorer [bigquery.jobs.insert](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/bigquery/bigquery/v2/bigquery.jobs.insert) method, I was able to insert a job using exactly the same request you have in your original code.

[image]